# How to narrow down the type usequery data with suspense and react-error-boundary?

Tags: react-query, trpc.io

I am using react query

the data received after usequery contains undefined. I want to remove undefined from this data.

usingQuery
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t1bn3.png)

root.tsx
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vM0XQ.png)

https://tkdodo.eu/blog/react-query-error-handling#error-boundaries

Refer to the above link for error boundary processing.
As a result, `return "...loading"` is done at the end, but `return "...loading"` is not necessary because I am using error boundaries and suspense. How can I make the function without `return "...loading"` in this case?

Should I consider HOC?

I tryed https://tkdodo.eu/blog/react-query-error-handling#error-boundaries doc

useQueryOptions
`{ suspense: true, useErrorBoundary: true }`
and `placeholderData` `initialData`

I couldn't get the results I wanted.

"no-non-null-assertion" was also considered, but there were conflicting parts with eslint settings, and there was no way to exclude only certain variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to use zod and as a result I solved it with the following code

```
// hooks/query.ts
const useSomeApi = () => {
    const { data } = useQuery(...);
    //userSchema = z.object({name: z.string()});
    const validResult = userSchema.parse(data);
    return {data: validResult}
}
```

If subsequent parsing fails, it is processed to throw an error to the error boundary.